# SpannableString - setTag

Tags: android

SpannableString does not have setTag, is there a possible workaround to this? It would be good to know behind the scenes which word has been clicked for extra data processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your own subclass of [`ClickableSpan`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ClickableSpan.html) that holds the data you want, and apply it to your `SpannableString`.

Comment: Since there are about three strings that are clickable in a SpannableString, will I be able to check which string the User has clicked with the above method?

Comment: @Ash: You will have three `ClickableSpan` objects. Whichever one the user clicks will be called with `onClick()`. When you create the `ClickableSpan` and attach a word to it via a data member, you will have access to that data in `onClick()`.